# Possibility Of Cracking WPA Password with Additional Information

Tags: passwords, wpa2

If one knows that a certain WPA2 CCMP encrypted network uses a password that is 16 characters and only numbers and uppercase letters (ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890) and has a handshake from that network does that make it possible to crack the password in a plausible amount of time?

I know it depends on the type of hardware used but generally what amount of an advantage could this information give you?

Comment: ... it means you know exactly how to craft your brute-force password library ...

Comment: I know but does that information give me a significant time advantage like 7 days instead of 7 years?

Comment: Check out this question. It's basically the same one you're asking: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/35278/bruteforce-on-10-characters-length-wpa2-password?rq=1

Comment: well, maybe 70 years instead of 7000 years, but yeah, that's the kind of advantage you get

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a great advantage, It's no longer a full brute-force (all charsets and and lengths), but rather a specific brute-force (16 long and two basic charsets)

Your best shot would be to do a [space-time-tradeoff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space%E2%80%93time_tradeoff) pre-computing all the possible keys with tools like pyrit, then use OCLHashcat to use GPU to compare the keys with the MIC.

If you don't own a powerful GPU or don't want to skyrocket your electrical bill, you can also leverage the cloud to crack it yourself, renting some EC2 instances on Amazon, Azure, Bluemix, etc. for few bucks, or online cracking services like the long-time-dead Cloudcraker or OnlinceHashCrack, GPUHash.me etc.

I've already answered this: [aircrack-ng fed with crunch taking ages](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/121302/aircrack-ng-fed-with-crunch-taking-ages/148979#148979)

Comment: Could you ball park how long this might take using pyrit and GPU cracking on an average computer? I am just trying to see if its work my time.

Comment: @NULL Sorry man, tbh I don't have my workstation no more. Gifted the SDD I was using to my sibling's new rig and I haven't taken the time to get a new laptop/storage device. So.. I'm out of game as on now :(